# Move/migrate vbox virtual machine to another computer along with snapshots

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, virtualbox

I have sun virtualbox(2.2) installed on windows xp and I've some VMs(ubuntu server) running  with many snapshots . How do I move virtualbox VDIs along with all the snapshots to new windows system?. I tried copying the base vdi and creating it newly on a new system and it worked fine but could not move the snapshots of the vms. I even tried copying `Virtualbox.xml` and machine's xml file to the new system and manually editing the snapshots location to the new place in the virtualbox.xml file, the snapshots are listed in the snapshots tab(but when I checked snapshots location in the vm's settings it's showing the default location having edited it)  but when I try to use the snapshots, reverting to current, it's not booting(some snapshots giving grub 2 error, some got stalled at the boot). I also tried export and import but only current state I could export and use it on the new system with no snapshots. Is there any way I could achieve this?. Please need help...

Answer (score 0):

You also have to edit the machine XML files, there's hardcoded paths to snapshots and disks in them.